# Creating a bingo game, table creation isn't placing numbers in correct columns

Tags: c#

B 1-15 |
I 16-30 |
N 31-45 |
G 46-60 |
O 61-75

The problem is in 'fillcard()' , I added some checks and comments where I believe the problem is occurring. The problem is in a typical bingo card the letters follow a certain number range as stated above, when the table is printed , those values don't correspond yet it is random. For example I will get a 24 in the B column or a 65 in the G column, the card is filled in 'fillcard()' and i'm not sure why this is occurring.
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;

```
namespace BINGO
{
    class Program
    {
        static string user;
        static bool bingo = false;
        static string[,] table = new string[5, 5];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fillcard(table);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BINGO, What is your name?");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + user + ", here is your bingo card.");
            printboard(table);
            Master(table, bingo);        
        }
        static string[,] Master(string[,] table, bool bingo)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (bingo == false)
            {   
                string letter = "";
                int number = 0;
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 5), B = rnd.Next(1, 15), I = rnd.Next(16, 30), N = rnd.Next(31, 45), G = rnd.Next(46, 60), O = rnd.Next(61, 75);
                switch (num)
                {
                    case 1:
                        letter = "B";
                        number = B;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        letter = "I";
                        number = I;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        letter = "N";
                        number = N;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        letter = "G";
                        number = G;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        letter = "O";
                        number = O;
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(letter + " " + number);
                var waitTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                var waitUntil = DateTime.Now + waitTime;

                waitUntil = DateTime.Now + waitTime;

                while (DateTime.Now <= waitUntil)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey(true);
                        Console.WriteLine("Do you have BINGO or a mark?");
                        string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                        if(response == "mark")
                        {
                            checkmark(table, number);
                            Console.Clear();
                            printboard(table);
                        }
                        else if(response == "bingo")
                        {

                        }
                    }

                }
            } 
            return table;
        }
        static string[,] checkmark(string[,] table, int number)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            { 
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if(table[i,j] == "X ")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (number == Convert.ToInt32(table[i, j]))
                    {
                        table[i, j] = "X ";
                    }
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
        static string[,] fillcard(string[,] table)
        {
            int i, j, step = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] prev = new int[100];
                string letter = "";
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Y
                {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //X
                {
                    int B = rnd.Next(1, 15), I = rnd.Next(16, 30), N = rnd.Next(31, 45), G = rnd.Next(46, 60), O = rnd.Next(61, 75);
                    switch (j)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            letter = Convert.ToString(B);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            letter = Convert.ToString(I);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            letter = Convert.ToString(N);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            letter = Convert.ToString(G);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            letter = Convert.ToString(O);
                            break;
                    }
                    bool next = false;
                    if(Convert.ToInt32(letter) < 10) //adds extra space for formatting
                    {
                        letter = (letter + " ");
                    }
                    if (!(step == 0))//Step is making sure it doesnt check for a previous value if it is the first value on the table
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < prev.Length; k++) //Checks for previous values in an array and if true it will subtract j and regenerate that letter.
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(letter) == prev[k])
                            {
                                if(j == 0)
                                {

                                }
                                else {
                                    j--;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                next = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (next == true)
                    {
                        if (i == 2 && j == 2)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(j);
                            Console.WriteLine(letter);
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            table[i, j] = Convert.ToString(letter);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(j);
                        Console.WriteLine(letter);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        table[i, j] = Convert.ToString(letter);
                    }
                    prev[step] = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
                    step++;
                }
            }

            return table;
        }
        static void printboard(string[,] table)
        {
            int i, j;
            string[] headings = { "B", "I", "N", "G", "O" };
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}      ", headings[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 2 && j == 2)
                        Console.Write("X      ");
                    else
                        Console.Write("{0}     ", table[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a function defined as `tableplace()`... So it isn't easy to see where your problem is.

Comment: I meant fillcard()

Comment: You should not declare `rnd = new Random()` each time inside the `while` loop. Since it gets seeded by the system clock, and the `while` loop will execute quickly, you will not get truly random numbers. You should declare it once at the beginning of the method (before the `while`), or as a class member (where you declare `user`, etc).

Comment: @Tanner then please update your question so it's clear what the problem is. Also, state exactly *how* the "table isn't getting generated correctly". Show what you expect and what you're actually seeing.

Comment: The problem is in 'tableplace()' ,  I added some checks in this link here [link](https://pastebin.com/ZR327i2W), The problem is in a typical bingo card the letters follow a certain number range as stated above, when the table is printed , those values don't correspond yet it is random. For example I will get a 24 in the B column or a 65 in the G column, the card is filled in 'fillcard()' and i'm not sure why this is occuring.

Comment: Please update your question (above) with the details of what is wrong. Not everyone reads the comments and this will get closed too quickly if you don't improve the actual question.

Comment: Done :)  Edited above

Answer (score 2):

What I would do it store your available values for each letter in a `List<int>`, and then pick a random one and remove it from the list each time. This way you get a valid value, and it will be random, and there will be no duplicates.

Since were dealing with five different letters, we'll have 5 different lists of available possibilies. And since the code to pick a random item from a list and remove it is the same, we can extract that part into a function. Also note that I'm declaring the `Rnd` variable at the class scope, so this method has access to it:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

    private static string GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(IList<int> items)
    {
        if (items == null || items.Count == 0) return string.Empty;

        var randomItem = items[Rnd.Next(items.Count)];
        items.Remove(randomItem);

        // The PadRight method will ensure each string is at least two characters wide
        return randomItem.ToString().PadRight(2, ' ');
    }
```

Now, in our `FillCard` method, we just need to create the five lists, and call our method for each letter:

```
    static void FillCard(string[,] table)
    {
        var BValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 15).ToList();
        var IValues = Enumerable.Range(16, 15).ToList();
        var NValues = Enumerable.Range(31, 15).ToList();
        var GValues = Enumerable.Range(46, 15).ToList();
        var OValues = Enumerable.Range(61, 15).ToList();

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                switch (col)
                {
                    case 0: // B
                        table[row, col] = GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(BValues);
                        break;
                    case 1: // I
                        table[row, col] = GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(IValues);
                        break;
                    case 2: // N
                        table[row, col] = GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(NValues);
                        break;
                    case 3: // G
                        table[row, col] = GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(GValues);
                        break;
                    case 4: // O
                        table[row, col] = GetRandomItemAndRemoveIt(OValues);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote a different method to display the array as a bingo card, so though it's not important to your question, here it is:

```
    public static void DisplayBingoCard(string[,] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗");
        Console.WriteLine("║ B  ║ I  ║ N  ║ G  ║ O  ║");
        Console.WriteLine("╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣");

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                Console.Write("║ " + values[row, col] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("║");

            if (row < 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we can create the array, use this method to fill it, and then output it to the screen:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        string[,] table = new string[5, 5];

        FillCard(table);
        DisplayBingoCard(table);

        Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: that is a great way of doing it, however, the rubric for this assignment wants me doing it based off of what we know, this is probably far more efficient but I don't understand it. Could you help me fix the logic error in my code? I appreciate the suggestion I just need to stick with this format for now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was homework. But to be honest I don't completely understand your logic, either. I have a feeling that you have a problem when you decrement `j` and set `next` to true, and then you still update the array with the duplicate value (only for a different letter, since you changed the value of `j` inside the loop). Take a look at that duplicate-checking code and try to simplify it a little.